# Paste without hitting enter

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to paste data (the .EntireRow.Select) into a new sheet ("Win") without having to hit Enter when choosing where to paste the data. I want the data to be pasted starting in column A, row one below the last row with entered data (lastRow is defined earlier in the code). Any advice? Thanks.

```
    If Archive = "Win" Then
        .EntireRow.Select
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
         Selection.Cut
            Sheets("Win").Select
            Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: If you want to avoid pasting, you can set two cells' values' to be equal to eachother, then set the one you wanted to CUT it form, to a blank cell.  Assuming you want the cut data to go to cell "F8" and the data comes from A1- `Activesheet.Range("F8").Value = Activesheet.Range("A1").Value` .  Then you can set A1 `= "" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using this code:

```
If Archive = "Win" Then
        .EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Win").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Other").Select
        Selection.Delete
    End If
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your code a little:

```
If Archive = "Win" Then
    EntireRow.Cut
        Sheets("Win").Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Paste
```

Where are you running into issues?

Comment: Thanks! That's much more concise than what I was running before. I want to be able to paste the data without hitting enter. Now, when I cut the data/select the sheet "Win", it requests for me to select the cell I want and hit enter - I want to automatically select the last cell used + 1 in column A and automatically paste the data.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of your data via a copy.com or dropbox link?